# Send selected checkbox' s value with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, checkbox

I have many checkbox like this

```
<table>
  <tr><td>data1</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='cek[]' name='cek[]' value='1' /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>data2</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='cek[]' name='cek[]' value='2' /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>data3</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='cek[]' name='cek[]' value='3' /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>data4</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='cek[]' name='cek[]' value='4' /></td></tr>
</table>
```

How to write the javascript and AJAX code to send the value which one I check?
when I check the data2's checkbox, the database about data2 should be changed..

this is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cek[]").clicked(function(){
    var cek_id = $("#cek[]").val();
    $.ajax({
      type  : "POST",
      url   : "update.php",
      data  : "id=" + cek_id
    });
  });
});
```

and this my update.php

```
<?php
  //here connection code
  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE data set checked='1' where id='$_POST[id]'");
?>
```

Comment: Show your javascript code also. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Post some code what you have tried

Comment: And give the value in the checkbox too, otherwise you will need to access the sibling content

Comment: i can't get which one checkbox that clicked by user with javascript >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){
         if($(this).is(":checked"))
         {
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'update.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: "id="+$(this).val(),
                 success:function(r){
                     // succcess call

                 }
             })

         }
  })
```

// every check-box will be read separately.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to each checkbox so you can identify them.
Use jquery and then you can simply use $("#checkbox1").checked